# kubernetes configmaps for binary file

Tags: kubernetes

My kubernetes version is 1.10.4.

I am trying to create a ConfigMap for java keystore files:

```
kubectl create configmap key-config --from-file=server-keystore=/home/ubuntu/ssl/server.keystore.jks --from-file=server-truststore=/home/ubuntu/ssl/server.truststore.jks --from-file=client--truststore=/home/ubuntu/ssl/client.truststore.jks --append-hash=false
```

It says `configmap "key-config" created`.

But when I describe the configmap I am getting null value:

```
$ kubectl describe configmaps key-config
Name:         key-config
Namespace:    prod-es
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
Events:  <none>
```

I know my version kubernetes support binary data as configmaps or secrets but I am not sure what is wrong with my approach.

Any input on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

`kubectl describe` does not show binary data in ConfigMaps at the moment (kubectl version v1.10.4); also the `DATA` column of the `kubectl get configmap` output does not include the binary elements:

```
$ kubectl get cm
NAME           DATA      AGE
key-config     0         1m
```

But the data is there, it's just a poor UI experience at the moment. You can verify that with:

```
kubectl get cm key-config -o json
```

Or you can use this friendly command to check that the ConfigMap can be mounted and the projected contents matches your original files:

`kubectl run cm-test --image=busybox --rm --attach --restart=Never --overrides='{"spec":{"volumes":[{"name":"cm", "configMap":{"name":"key-config"}}], "containers":[{"name":"cm-test", "image":"busybox", "command":["sh","-c","md5sum /cm/*"], "volumeMounts":[{"name":"cm", "mountPath":"/cm"}]}]}}'`